# Dynamic jQuery dropdown to show/hide div elements based on selected option

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an events list with a category filter at the top. The category filter will be a `<select>` dropdown, with dynamically generated `<option>` variables. When an option is selected, the events list should then be filtered to only show elements containing that text.

The HTML for this events list is generated by the content management system so I can't edit this directly, but I can use CSS and jQuery to manipulate it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="event-filters">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <select id="categoryFilter">
            <option>All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="msl_eventlist">
    <div>
        <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
            // Some other event details
            <div class="msl_event_types">
                <a>Free</a>
                <a>Day</a>
                <a>Online</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
            // Some other event details
            <div class="msl_event_types">
                <a>Night</a>
                <a>Online</a>
                <a>Club</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like each `<option>` for the dropdown to be generated by the `<a>` elements within `.msl_event_types`, without creating the same one twice if there's repetition (e.g. more than one event being an online event, as above). Because there's 30+ different types possible, I don't want to write them all in manually and have them all visible at all times - I want the script to see what's actually being used and create the options accordingly.

When one of these options is selected, the list should then filter either by the text within the `<a>` element or by the relevant class (`msltypeFree`, `msltypeOnline`, etc), whichever is easier.

The option list should also include an 'all' option, which should be the default option as well as being a selectable option to reset the category filter.

Normally I'm able to take a stab at something like this but I honestly don't even know where to begin with it, so any help is really appreciated!

**Edit:** Added in the  input to the top, as I can edit the HTML outside of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to the onchange event of the select input. Get the value of this selectbox and the you can use jQuery to filter the elements that contain the selected value. You can then hide or show them when they contain the value or not.

```js
$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var foundTypes = [];
  //get all types (without duplicates)
  $('.msl_event_types a').each((i, el) => {
    var type = $(el).text();
    if (!foundTypes.includes(type)) {
      foundTypes.push(type);
    }
  });

  //Create option elements for all found types
  foundTypes.forEach((type) => $('#categoryFilter').append(`<option>${type}</option>`));
});


//Add an event listner to the change event of the selectbox
$('#categoryFilter').on('change', (e) => {
  //Get the selected value
  var selectedValue = $(e.currentTarget).val();

  if (selectedValue === 'All') {
    $('.event_item').show();
  } 
  else {
    //Iterate over all event items
    $('.event_item').each((i, el) => {
      var $eventItem = $(el);
      //filter the event types based on the selected value, if the result of the filter still contains elements then show the event item, if not hide it.
      $eventItem.find('.msl_event_types a').filter((i, el) => $(el).text().trim() === selectedValue).length > 0 ? $eventItem.show() : $eventItem.hide();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event-filters">
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <select id="categoryFilter">
      <option>All</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="msl_eventlist">
  <div>
    <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
      // Some other event details
      <div class="msl_event_types">
        <a>Free</a>
        <a>Day</a>
        <a>Online</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
      // Some other event details
      <div class="msl_event_types">
        <a>Night</a>
        <a>Online</a>
        <a>Club</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the response but I think you missed part of my question. I don't want to write in all of the options myself because there's 30+ potential different ones and I don't want them all to be visible all of the time. The script you've provide filters them perfectly, but I also want it to generate the options too, based on the types listed within the event item.

Comment: @ElliotParker Sorry, i missed that part. I updated my answer, but I see you also found a solution yourself. I used a 2 step solution by first write the types to an array (without duplicating values) and then use the array to build the options. If you got a solution for your problem please accept the answer that suits you best so we know you don't need help anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the answer as much I understand your question. Hope it will works for you :)

```js
 
 var eventArray=[];
 var filteredEventArray=[];
 
    $(".msl_eventlist .msl_event_types a").each(function( index,        element){
    var element=$(element).text().trim();
        eventArray.push(element);
        })
        
       filteredEventArray= [...new Set( eventArray)]
          $(filteredEventArray).map(function(index, element){
          $("#categoryFilter").append('<option>'+element+'</option')
    })
    
    
    
    $('#categoryFilter').on('change', (e) => {
    var filteredEvent=e.target.value;
  
    
  $('.event_item').each((index, element) => {
    var event = $(element);  
      if(filteredEvent==="All"){
      $(event).show()
    }
    else{
    $(event).find('.msl_event_types a').filter((index, ele) =>   
    $(ele).text().trim() === filteredEvent).length > 0  ?                   $(event).show() : $(event).hide();   }
  });
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event-filters">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <select id="categoryFilter">
            <option>All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="msl_eventlist">
    <div>
        <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
            <div class="msl_event_types">
                <a>Free</a>
                <a>Day</a>
                <a>Online</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event_item msltypeFree msltypeDay msltypeOnline">
            <div class="msl_event_types">
                <a>Night</a>
                <a>Online</a>
                <a>Club</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right so I managed to do it using a combination of Mark's answer and some other useful bits I found online, and adapting everything to suit my situation.

Works a treat!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Define variables for category filter
    var events = $('.event_item');

    // For each event item, set a title and ID and append as option on category dropdown
    events.each( function(i) {
        $(this).find('.msl_event_types a').each(function () {
            title = $(this).text();
            id = $(this).text().replace(/[\W\s]/g, '').toLowerCase();
            if (!$('#categoryFilter option#'+id).length) {
                $('#categoryFilter').append('<option id="'+ id+'">'+ title +'</option>');
            }
        });
    });
});
        
$('#categoryFilter').on('change', (e) => {
    
    var selectedValue = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    
    console.log(selectedValue);

    if (selectedValue != "All") {
        $('.event_item').each((i, el) => {
            var $eventItem = $(el);
            $eventItem.find('.msl_event_types a').filter((i, el) => $(el).text().trim() === selectedValue).length > 0  ? $eventItem.show() : $eventItem.hide();   
        });
    } else {
        $('.event_item').show();
    }
});
```